# Cannot read property 'include' of undefined - Express Routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to do some basic routing depending on what is ticked/checked on the first (parent) page. So if the first page had 3 options and the user selects 2 of them then I'd expect the user to see the two (child) pages selected but not the third (as it was not selected).

My approach was on the first (parent) page to do the following:

```
router.post('/first-page/', function (req, res, next) {
  var errors = []
  var myCheckboxes = req.body.checkboxes
  if (myCheckboxes === 'undefined') {
   //error validation
  } if (myCheckboxes.includes('first')) {
    res.redirect('first-option-page')
    return
  } if (myCheckboxes.includes('second')) {
    res.redirect('second-option-page')
    return
  } if (myCheckboxes.includes('third')) {
    res.redirect('third-option-page')
    return
  } else {
    res.redirect('move-on')
    return
  }
})
```

Then for the other pages what I was doing is used the `req.session.data['checkboxes']` and run through the loop again to see if the second and/or the third option page is selected and if they are then show those pages until eventually it is has gone through it all.

**The problem I got is that it is then throwing the error "Cannot read property 'include' of undefined" for the child pages.**

```
router.post('/first-option-page/', function (req, res, next) {
  var errors = []
  var myCheckboxes = req.session.checkboxes
  if (myCheckboxes.includes('second')) {
    res.redirect('second-option-page')
    return
  } if (myCheckboxes.includes('third')) {
    res.redirect('third-option-page')
    return
  } else {
    res.redirect('move-on')
    return
  }
})
```

Is there a slicker way to run through the pages or what can I do to solve the error please?

Comment: that's because myCheckboxes(req.session.checkboxes) can be null value

Comment: `else {` is not needed when returning inside if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, I wrote the `req.session.checkboxes` incorrectly it should have been `req.session.data['checkboxes']`